# How to duplicate text every line in textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to duplicate text every line in textarea using jquery..

```html
<!--
first, im gonna paste my text in input like this..

<textarea id="input">
one

two






three

four


five



six


seven


(and so on...)
</textarea>



and the result is like this..
<textarea id="Result">
one
one
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
three
three
four
four
four
five
five
five
five
six
six
six
seven
seven
seven
seven
</textarea>

duplicating text is depend on break line..
-->
here is my code:
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="input" ></textarea>
<textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="output" ></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Process!" />
```

I hope you can help me guys, thanks in advance..

Comment: So you want to copy the content from the first textarea into the second one?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
var invalue = $('#input').val();
$('#output').val(invalue.replace(/^(.*)$/gm, '$1\n$1'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7547pryt/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have javsascript tagged in the question I thought I would give you a demo without using jQuery.

> Interested in using this method please comment blow and i will explain anything you don't understand about this method.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var a=document.getElementById('input');
    a.addEventListener('input',MyFunction,false);
    a.focus();
}
function MyFunction(){
 var DataIn=event.target.value;
 DataIn = DataIn.replace(/(\n){1,}/g, '\n');
 document.getElementById('output').value=DataIn;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="input" ></textarea>
<textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="output" ></textarea>
```

> **Update:** jQuery method

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){
    $('#output').val($(this).val().replace(/(\n){1,}/g, '\n'));
});
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: @PhDev This uses javascript, what part don't your understand and i will add comments into the answer to explain anything you don't understand?